# How much memory do 1000 shared pointers take?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

1. How much memory do (e.g.) 1000 shared pointers take?
2. is it 16 x 1000 bytes?
3. Does it differ for 32 and 64bit system?

Comment: Are you including the objects pointed to, and the overhead associated with each of those? Also, shared pointers *to what*?

Comment: @Caleth nope. only the pointers themselves. I don't think the memory size of a pointer wouldn't change depending on poing to different objects, right?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is not a type, it does not have a size. There is no requirement for `sizeof(std::shared_ptr<int>)` equals `sizeof(std::shared_ptr<void>)`, however I can't think of any reasons for them to be different

Comment: You can test it yourself with a simple `cout << sizeof(Whatever) <<   " " << sizeof(Whatever[100]) << "\n";` Very likely, shared_ptr will hold one or more pointer, so its size depends on `sizeof (void*)`, meaning you will get different results for 32 an 64bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a typical implementation, [`std::shared_ptr` holds only two pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr#Implementation_notes).

So 1000 shared pointers take up `1000 * 2 * sizeof(pointer)` bytes of memory.

- Size of a pointer is 4 bytes on all 32-bit systems that follow ILP32 data model.
- Size of a pointer is 8 bytes on a 64-bit systems that follow LP64 data model (Most Unix and Unix-like systems) or LLP64 data model (Microsoft Windows x86-64).

Note: The size of the control block (which is implementation dependent) and the size of the object the shared pointer shares ownership of are not part of this.

Comment: Added a note to that effect. Thanks.

Comment: @Baran: Does this answer your question?

Comment: is there no storage held up for the reference counter?

Comment: @Avi: The control block contains this information. Pls see the link in the answer for more details.